# Show that there exists no integer $n$ such that $n^3 - n + 3$ divides $n^3 + n^2 + n + 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, divisibility

My attempt:

For $n^3 - n + 3$ to divide $n^3 + n^2 + n + 2$, it should also divide $(n^3 + n^2 + n + 2) - (n^3 - n + 3) = n^2 + 2n - 1$. I did this to reduce the degree, but I don't think it helps.

Comment: Hint: $|n^3-n+3|>|n^2+2n-1|$ for $n$ of sufficiently large magnitude.

Comment: Well Done... Reducing the degree is the best way to solve this kind of problem. Now, you know that when $n$ increases, $n^3$ increases faster than $n^2$, and at the specific moment, $n^3-n+3$ will be bigger than $n^2+2n-1$, while $n^3-n+3|n^2+2n-1$ so it's contradiction.

Comment: Ok, this works when $n^3−n+3>n^2+2n−1$, but as $n \to -\infty$, $n^3−n+3 \to -\infty$, while $n^2+2n−1 \to \infty$, so there do exist $n$ such that $n^3−n+3<n^2+2n−1$

Comment: @BillDubuque I don't see how I can further reduce the degree

Comment: @FadeelKhan Well, you don't really have to go to $\infty$, for all integers, $|n^3-n+3|>|n^2+2n-1|$…

Comment: @Macavity How do we know that $|n^3-n+3|>|n^2+2n-1|$ is true?

Comment: @FadeelKhan Induction should do it easily, though you may have to handle $n<0$ as a separate induction case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way to show this.  $n^3-n+3=n(n^2-1)+3=(n-1)n(n+1)+3$, so is obviously divisible by $3$. However $n^3+n^2+n+2$ isn't divisible by $3$ (you need to only check for $n=0,\pm1$).

Answer (score 1):

If some $n$ works, then the greatest common divisor of $n^3 - n + 3$ and $n^3 + n^2 + n + 2$ must be $|n^3 - n + 3|$. But by the  Euclidean algorithm
\begin{align*}
&\phantom{=} (n^3 - n + 3, n^3 + n^2 + n+ 2) \\
&= (n^3 - n + 3, n^2 + 2n - 1)\\
&= (n^2 + 2n - 1, - 2n^2 + 3)\\
&= (n^2 + 2n - 1, 4n+5)\\
&= (4n^2 + 8n - 4, 4n+5)\\ 
&\text{[where we note that }4n+5 \text{ is odd hence it cannot be divided by } 4]\\
&= (4n+5, 3n - 4)\\
&= (3n - 4, n + 9)\\
&= (-31, n + 9)\in  \{\pm 1, \pm 31\},
\end{align*}
thus $|n^3 - n + 3| = (31, n+9)$. So possible cases for $n^3 - n + 3$ are $\pm 1, \pm 31$, or $n^3 - n \in \{-34, -4, -2, 28\}$. Note that $f(x) := x^3 - x, x\in \Bbb R$ is odd and increases on $(-\infty, -1), (1, +\infty)$ respectively, and that $f(-1) = f(1)= f(0) = 0$.

Try values: $f(3) = 24 < 28 < 34, f(4) = 60 > 34 > 28$, so both $-34$ and $28$ cannot be attained. $f(-2) = -f(2) = -6 < -4 $, so $-4, -2$ are also out of range. Therefore no $n$ works.